# UNIX command which displays lines which contains specified string

Tags: unix

I have file which contains something like :

Hi how are you
how are you
you are genius
hi i'am fine
this is test session

I need UNIX command which displays lines which contains "are" word.

Comment: please refrain from using lines like "how are you"; they are not constructive; also don't abuse stackoverflow questions to post your "test sessions".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hmm, this is really the most basic use of `grep`.

```
grep -w "are" myfile.txt
```